# Can apt-get autoremove remove system files?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-managers

I tried to install Python 3 on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and while using `apt` i found this:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract gcc-5-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libblosc1 libboost-filesystem1.58.0:i386 libboost-system1.58.0:i386
  libboost-wave1.58.0 libbsd0:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libcapnp-0.5.3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl1-mesa:i386 libelf1:i386
  libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgd3:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386
  libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386
  liblcms2-2:i386 libllvm6.0:i386 liblog4cplus-1.1-9 libltdl7:i386 libmirclient9:i386 libmircommon7:i386 libmircore1:i386
  libmirprotobuf3:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmspack0 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopenimageio1.7
  libopenshadinglanguage1.8 libopensubdiv libopenvdb3.1 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpcap0.8:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libprotobuf-lite9v5:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev
  libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsensors4:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio6.1 libsndio6.1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
  libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx3:i386 libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-24
  linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-24-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-24-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic p7zip python-all python-all-dev
  python-dev python-wheel python2.7-dev python3-numpy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

I can do `sudo apt autoremove` but i fear that packages like `linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic` are important and after deleting it my Ubuntu will be broken. Who can say is it safe to do autoremove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  apt-get autoremove will only remove files which are not in use by any installed package. Since all the packages you need to run your system have been installed apt-get autoremove will not remove any important system file.

If you require one of the package listed in the apt-get autoremove, you can always install it manually using:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.15-0.29-generic
```

Then when you run your autoremove the package will no longer be in the list.

I noticed that among the files in question there was a kernel file.  If you want to know if that particular version of the kernel is in use right now, use:

```
uname -a
```

Comment: but what if `autoremove` will harm `apt-get`?

Comment: That should never be the case, apt-get is an installed package and therefore any dependencies wouldn't be "autoremove"d

Comment: so autoremove cannot remove packages that are using?

Comment: autoremove goes through the catalog and remove any left over packages that were not directly installed and that are not required by packages that are installed.  So literally, its just cleaning up the stuff you never requested.  Say that you install apache, it will install a lot of libraries.  If you remove apache, all these libraries will be left behind until you run autoremove.  The only thing you have to watch for, is if you started using one of the depencies say "Python" but never actually installed it yourself; then it will be removed.

Comment: oh it was safe :)

Comment: @VladGavriuk if the answer answered your question, please mark your question answered!

Comment: oh sorry i forgot

Answer (score 1):

`apt autoremove` will only delete packages no more required. However, You can always remove a package directly on which some system or utility package is depending. In this case, `autoremove` will work like fission reaction chain and delete everything one by one. It happened to me.

Answer (score -2):

It has the potential to remove things you dont want to be removed. It just wiped everything from my install. Even gedit.